# creating customized search box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a customized search box. I tried the following but getting weird results.

this is my css code

```
.inputboxSearch {
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
border: 1px solid #333333;
background:url('images/searchbox.png') no-repeat; 
padding-right:20px;
}
```

where, searchbox.png is a full a image (180*30 png) of a searchbox. Then i have tghe following code.

```
<input class="inputboxSearch" type='text' name='search' size='25'/>
```

But, how it appears is that, the search box image comes inside of the input box, and it is only half displayed. Rest is not visible. But wat i expected was, the search box should encompass the input box. The revers is happening here anyways. How to solve this

Comment: What browser and version are you testing this in?

Comment: i am using chrome browser ( not sure of the version ).

Comment: can you put up some running example of the html and css?

Comment: Can you make a picture of what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: sure, please have a look at this http://calyxteltech.com/temp/index.php

Comment: The search box is in the right corner.

Comment: @Keoki, Wat i expected was like, the image only should be visible and not the input box such that the user thinks he types inside the filed in the image rather than the input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set .inputboxSearch border to none, and increase its height to 30px:

```
.inputboxSearch {
    background: url("images/searchbox.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Wow. That was great. Thank you very much. But, when the user types, it is like he is typing out of the box :( pls have the preview here.  http://calyxteltech.com/temp/index.php

Comment: what i mean is that, the rectangular box which comes by default on clicking, defeats the purpose. How to remove that

Comment: @CHID if you add `padding-left: 20px;` or something like that, it will fix the left side...I'm not sure about the right side.  Also, if you think my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the best answer :)

Comment: @CHID sorry, just saw your new comment, let me read it and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @CHID you mean the big orange rectangle that you get when you click the input box in chrome?  That's specific to Chrome and Safari, you don't get the same thing in Firefox 5 beta or IE 9...I'm not really sure what you can do about that.  If you ask another question about it, maybe someone else knows and can help you?  Thanks for the answer accept by the way, always appreciated :)

Comment: oh sure :) yes, i meant the rectangular box. No problems. You helped me solved the problem. Thanks much

Comment: @CHID I found out how to solve the orange rectangle thing for Chrome.  If you use `outline: none;` that will get rid of the orange rectangle in Chrome, see http://jsfiddle.net/ET4Tv/4/ for example.